# What is the justification for the vector $(b, -a)$ being orthogonal to $\mathbf{V}=(a,b)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

I am currently studying the textbook *Partial Differential Equations: An Introduction*, second edition, by Walter A. Strauss. Chapter **1.2 First-Order Linear Equations** says the following:

> Let us solve
> $$au_x + bu_y = 0,$$
> where $a$ and $b$ are constants not both zero.
>
> **Geometric Method** The quantity $au_x + bu_y$ is the directional derivative of $u$ in the direction of the vector $\mathbf{V} = (a, b) = a \mathbf{i} + b \mathbf{j}$. It must always be zero. This means that $u(x, y)$ must be constant in the direction of $\mathbf{V}$. The vector $(b, -a)$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf{V}$. The lines parallel to $\mathbf{V}$ (see Figure 1) have the equations $bx - ay = \text{constant}$. (They are called the *characteristic lines*.) The solution is constant on each such line. Therefore, $u(x, y)$ depends on $bx - ay$ only. Thus the solution is
> $$u(x, y) = f(bx - ay), \tag{2}$$
> where $f$ is any function of one variable.
> [image]

What is the justification for the vector $(b, -a)$ being orthogonal to $\mathbf{V}$? And I mean this in terms of proving/justifying the one-sided implication "something implies that the vector $(b, -a)$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf{V}$" (so $\text{something} \Rightarrow \text{the vector $(b, -a)$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf{V}$}$), rather than the converse implication "the vector $(b, -a)$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf{V}$ implies something" ($\text{the vector $(b, -a)$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf{V}$} \Rightarrow \text{something}$). Furthermore, I'm looking for a justification that starts without knowledge of $(b, -a)$, and then derives $(b, -a)$ itself.

Comment: The fact that $(a,b).(b,-a)=0$ implies that $(b,-a)$ is orthogonal to $(a,b)(=\mathbf V)$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Oh, that's true. But I was looking to start without knowledge of $(b, -a)$, and then deriving $(b, -a)$ itself, if that makes sense.

Comment: Then you solve the equation $(a,b).(x,y)=0(\iff ax+by=0)$. One solution is $(x,y)=(b,-a)$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ahh, yes, you're right. That answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: It was not clear to me that this is what you wanted. I have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vectors which are orthogonal to $(a,b)(=\mathbf V)$ are the vectors $(x,y)$ such that$$(a,b).(x,y)=0(\iff ax+by=0).$$And a solution of $ax+by=0$ is $(x,y)=(b,-a)$.